# Autocompletions in IDEs don't work for cv2

Tags: python, autocomplete, realsense

I started to work with intel RealSense devices which uses pyrealsense2 python library. After installing that library with a great effort on Ubuntu, I also install opencv and numpy libraries. Since these libraries contain many many functions, autocompletion plays a big role.

However, it does not work for me with some libraries. For example, in VSCode and PyCharm, autocompletion for numpy library works well but for cv2 & pyrealsense2 it does not.

numpy was installed with pip, pyrealsense2 was installed from source and cv2 was installed with both pip and PyCharm packages.

I searched it for a long time but did not find a useful answer. If you want additional information don't hesitate to ask, please.

Comment: I followed the instructions given in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments and installed the libraries again in that folder produced by venv command. It solved the problem with cv2 but autocompletion for pyrealsense2 still does not work

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, then update your question with specific details, and things you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Pycharm, but for VSCode, you can select the interpreter path, and if you're using the correct Python environment that has the library, it will surely show up

[cv2 autocompletes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp0Np.png)